# Validate and format JSON without alphabetically sorting the data with 'jsonlint'

Tags: python

The package `python-demjson` provides the `jsonlint` command.

I use it like this to format my JSON data:

```
jsonlint -f input.json > output.json
```

But the data is not in the original order any more, it sorts `<key:value>` alphabetical:

---

Orignal JSON:

```
{"beta":123, "alpha":123}
```

After `jsonlint`:

```
{ "alpha":123
  "beta":123 
}
```

---

Can I disable alphabetical sorting in `jsonlint`?
Or should I use other JSON-validator for it? Please only suggest offline tools.

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You mean you want to tell `jsonlint` not to sort the data but keep the original order, or if that isn't possible, you want an alternative tool that does this?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is a website that you can download and use offline also ok? Maybe you can rework the underlying JS to run locally from the command line... I've posted the link in my answer.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out https://github.com/DaAwesomeP/jsonlintpro-desktop or https://github.com/trentm/json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from the manpage of `jsonlint`:

```
[...]


-f, --format
      Reformat the JSON (if legal) to stdout

[...]

    When reformatting, all members of objects  (associative  arrays)
    are  always  output  in  lexigraphical  sort order.

[...]
```

That means if you use the `-f` option to reformat your JSON data, this tool will always alphabetically sort the entries.

You have to look for alternative software to do this. I will edit this answer and add some if I find any.

- You could look at the site http://www.json.fr/ where all validating is done client-side, that means you can save the site on your computer (save full site, not HTML only!) and then still use it offline by opening the downloaded file in your browser.

  It does not change the element order by sorting it. Your example input becomes to:

  ```
  {
    "beta": 123,
    "alpha": 123
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for information about web-validators but i'd like to have offline one.

Comment: @UNIm95 As I said, you just need to download the site and it will work offline. I tested it! Right-click on the site and select "Save page as...".

Comment: There is also `js` :)